# Timestamp REST API endpoint links show 404 error not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I just started to learn backend. I tested locally with postman and localhost, all seems to work. But when I upload to github, clicking on the API endpoint hyperlinks from index.html it throws 404 error. I might be missing something.

Any help with why that could be happening would be great!

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Timestamp and Microservices</title>
  <script src="./server.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<container>
<h2 id="title">Timestamp and Microservices</h2>
<h4>Example Usage:</h4>
<a href="api/2015-12-25">[project url]/api/2015-12-25</a><br>
<a href="api/1451001600000">[project url]/api/1451001600000</a>
<h4>Example Output:</h4>
<p>{"unix":1451001600000, "utc":"Fri, 25 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT"}</p>
</container>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//server.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/api/:datestring?', (req, res) => {
    let datestring = req.params.datestring
    let date

    // if datestring is empty
    if (!datestring) {
        date = new Date()
    }
    // if datestring is not empty
    else {
        // if datestring is a number string
        if (!isNaN(datestring)) {
            // convert it to interger
            datestring = parseInt(datestring)
            date = new Date(datestring)
            // res.json({datestring: datestring, typeofdatestring: typeof(datestring), date: typeof(date)})
        }
        // if datestring is a string like 2020-01-01
        else {
            date = new Date(datestring)
            // res.json({datestring: datestring, typeofdatestring: typeof(datestring), date: typeof(date)})
        }
    }     

    // determine if date is a string or an integer 
    if (date.toString() === "Invalid Date") {
        res.json({error: date.toString()})
    }
    else {
        res.json({Unix: date.getTime(), UTC: date.toUTCString()})
    }
})

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Have you deployed this code? 
is your backend running and printing this line ? 
`Your app is listening on port`

Comment: when i typed "node server.js" in the command line in VScode, it shows:
"Your app is listening on port 3000".

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/index.html ` what are you getting by hitting this on browser?

Comment: I run nodemon server.js then type in http://localhost:3000/index.html. I got "Cannot GET /index.html"

Comment: I hope you have public folder in your root directory and a file named index.html inside that

Comment: I moved it in public folder and run index.html in there but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Still getting the same issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232698/discussion-between-trily84-and-rohit-singh).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because I deployed to github which only support static files. So I ended up deployed to Heroku and it works!